# Appending partial onto view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I currently have a partial being rendered via a click and an ajax call. The partial gets rendered at the top of the page, however on refresh the partial goes away(which is expected). I am wondering if there is anyway to have this partial append to the view after the button is clicked and it is rendered for the first time. I don't really want to create a db field checking to see if it has been clicked.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens to trigger the page refresh?  Clicking on a link? Submitting a form?  Some javascript?

Comment: I think creating a db fields is the best way you can solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about the sequence of events here.

- user makes request 1 to server
- page 1 is rendered out
- user makes ajax call to server
- partial is added to page
- user makes request 2 to server
- page 2 is rendered out.

AT THIS LAST POINT, rails needs to "decide" to add the partial on.  It can base its decision on a few different things:

- something in the database, eg in the user's preferences
- a cookie
- something in the session (possibly set via a previous form submission)
- something in params

You can decide which of these is the best option.  Cookies feel like the best way, as they can be set in the client or the server, when that partial is added to the previous page.  I guess your choice might depend on how permanent you want this change to be.

Comment: great ans Max. Since cookie is signed in `production` wont it be harder to set cookie in client side?

Comment: You don't need to use a signed cookie for this, i think.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing walkthrough @MaxWilliams. I have chosen to go with a cookie and can set the value of it to a string or bool, but am having trouble setting it to the id of an object. I am currently doing `cookies[:commentid] = { value: current_comment.id }` but the value of the cookie just remains blank. However if i did something like `cookies[:commentid] = { value: "testtest" }` the cookie would set to that value. Any ideas with that?

Comment: Nevermind, :) Hour long brain fart. Thanks a ton @MaxWilliams